# How to see your 'old' professions?

Tags: guild-wars-2

Is there a way to know which professions a character previously had on which level?

Comment: Are you referring to seeing the "base" professions as opposed to specializations, e.g. Guardian instead of Dragonhunter?

Answer (score 4):

Professions are your class in GW2. If you mean your crafting disciplines (referred to as "professions" in other games), the answer is that it shows on the login screen, when you mouseover your character.

[image: Professions]

On my first character in this image, my active crafting disciplines are shown as icons on my character (Weaponsmith, Tailor, and Artificer), but in the mouseover tooltip, it also shows Jeweler, which is an inactive crafting discipline on this character.

Comment: What is your first character there? I don't recognize the symbol.

Comment: @zozo It's a Tempest, the Elite Specialization for Elementalists.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be the case for me. I started playing again this weekend after years of inactivity, and my old characters have no crafting disciplines listed whatsoever (but definite. **However** I haven't logged in with them yet, maybe that gets refreshed after logging in. As a software developer, it makes some sense that the new features of showing crafting disciplines on the character select screen will only be triggered by logging in (or even more logically, logging OUT) with the character.